# Formula to update multi-picklist with Process Builder

Tags: formula, process-builder, picklist, process-automation

I've created a process to update a multi-picklist (Cloud Name) based on some words contained in a text field (Title) - it works but due to the pick values I am getting false positive.

[image]

> if(Contains([Contact].Title , "Marketing Cloud"), "Marketing Cloud;", "") 
>      +if(Contains([Contact].Title , "Commerce Cloud"), "Commerce Cloud;", "") 
>      +if(Contains([Contact].Title , "B2B Commerce Cloud"), "B2B Commerce Cloud;", "")

My problem is, if the Title Contains B2B Commerce Cloud, the process populates with both "B2B Commerce Cloud" and " Commerce Cloud". 
Is there a way around this?

Comment: Do you want to skip `Commerce Cloud` if the title contains `B2B Commerce Cloud`?

Comment: If contains B2B Commerce Cloud, I want the picklist to populate only with B2B Commerce Cloud  and not also with Commerce cloud. A title can contain both Commerce Cloud and B2B Commerce cloud, than the picklist should be updated with Commerce Cloud and B2B Commerce cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the condition below.
While checking for `Commerce Cloud` you can get rid of `B2B Commerce Cloud` from the title, using the `SUBSTITUTE` method.

```
if(Contains([Contact].Title , "Marketing Cloud"), "Marketing Cloud;", "") + 
if(Contains(SUBSTITUTE([Contact].Title, "B2B Commerce Cloud", "") , "Commerce Cloud"), "Commerce Cloud;", "") +
if(Contains([Contact].Title , "B2B Commerce Cloud"), "B2B Commerce Cloud;", "")
```

Comment: still the same result ... If I put B2B Commerce Cloud in the Title, the multi-picklist is populated with both Commerce Cloud and B2B Commerce Cloud

Comment: Correction: your formula partially works: if contains B2B Commerce Cloud it will update  only with B2B Commerce Cloud, but if contains both B2B Commerce Cloud and Commerce Cloud it will only update with B2B Commerce Cloud.

Comment: @CalinBostan can you update the new code in the question?

Comment: @CalinBostan is there any separator for those titles like `,` or `-` something like that?

Comment: In the Title? no ... there is no standard, it can be "space" , . - ) ( pretty much anything

Comment: I have updated my answer please check now. @CalinBostan

Comment: It is perfect, thank you